# What is data rate?

Tags: communication, data

What is the definition of data rate?

What is the unit of it?

Is it related to successful bits?

Comment: did you google? is this homework?

Comment: wiki goes to some different terms, google gives a card but it a bit vague I think. http://lmgtfy.com/?q=what+is+data+rate

Comment: Google card gives : The speed with which data can be transmitted from one device to another.  But what is meant by transmitted? Please refer to the 3rd question and be very specific.

Comment: If all your bits were "unsuccessful" (i.e. did not reach the other end for some reason), would you count that in your data rate calculation?

Comment: Yes, check the answer below. Data rate is misused by many researchers. Data rate is just the sending speed. Answer by T J is very good with each word being used correctly and carefully.

Comment: Objection is raised, why is the question on hold? It is completely related to electrical engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

definition of data rate is the number of bits / characters / symbols sent over a specific time. The unit for data rate would be bit per second (b/s) or byte per second (B/s). Data rate is what the system is able to send to another device, and is not related to the number of bits are useful or not for the system that is receiving it.